# Cannot connect to EC2 instance more than once via SSH (OSX Terminal)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

### Update

This may be to do with my account potentially being in an 'isolated' state as per this post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?start=0&threadID=239202&tstart=0

I'm going to contact AWS and ask them if this is the issue.

### Original Post

I'm fairly new to AWS but getting a recurring problem with connecting to EC2 via SSH. In short, I seem to be only able to connect once via SSH to my instance - all future attempts time out. The only fix is to stop it and start it each time.

Here is as much detail as I can provide - really hoping you guys can help me out here!

- Video of timeout:

  [Timeout Video](https://screencast.com/t/cqRxtV0W1uaO)
- EC2 is a T2 Micro:

  [EC2 Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru6zf.png)
- My EC2 is in a custom VPC
  -My Security Group has Port 22 open to the world and outbound it can access everything:

  - [SG - Inbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76q3T.png)
  - [SG - Oubound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEfnH.png)
- I'm using a public subnet in my VPC

  - My Network Access Control List (NACL) is default:

    [NACL - Inbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DbZ6.png)

    [NACL - Outbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN1IC.png)
- Route table has a route out to my Internet Gateway (which works fine):

  [My Route Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNd11.png)
- When I connect first time it's fine:
- After a few mins, I can't connect again:

  (see video at top of post)

Notes:
- Not that it matters but when I do successfully SSH in, I can curl webpages and get a response
- I'm tethering from my phone but doesn't seem to be affecting things (I think this didn't work at home either)
- If I just wait a minute or two after first SSH'ing in and exiting, when I try to reconnect after a couple of mins it will just time out

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have some application running and if it's a t2/t3 series instance, your instance  is mostly likely running out of CPU credits leaving no processing power to establish the connection. Please [edit] your post and add details of what type of instance, what processes are running and cloudwatch graphs as well

Comment: Thanks a lot @SathyajithBhat - I've updated the post accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was that AWS had for some reason set an 'isolated' flag in my account (I must have deactivated this a long time ago and it still had that flag on).

FYI I don think you can see this 'isolated' flag anywhere in the UI but if you raise a case with AWS they very quickly checked and removed it.